# Adding a subscription to iCal via Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, icalendar

I'd like to add a subscription in iCal like it does itself with Address Book: Address Book provides iCal with the birthdays of my contacts.
I would like to add something like that to iCal: I want to calculate Eastern and depending holidays and have iCal pull these dates from my program.

Does anyone have ideas for Cocoa APIs on where to start that endeavor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [CalCalendarStore Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/CalendarStoreProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to start with.

Comment: Note that the Birthdays calendar uses a special, private API. This is to make it non-editable by the user, while still updating even with Address Book not running. So you can't match it exactly. But as Abizer points out, the Calendar Store can be used to create and edit a calendar programmatically